# Peggy's age in Avengers Endgame

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-america-the-first-avenger

The first Captain America movie happens in the 40s. Steve falls in love with Peggy then.

In Avengers Endgame, Cap and Ironman travel to 1970. Cap sees Peggy then, she doesn't seem to have aged a day since the 40s.

How does this work, shouldn't Peggy have been 30 years older than we saw her in Captain America: The First Avenger?

Comment: My understanding is that after returning the stone in the 1970s he probably quantum/time travelled to the 1940s post Captain America disappearing from that timeline.

Comment: @jared Im referring to the scene in 1970 when Steve is looking to steal Pym capsules. He sees Peggy in the next room.

Comment: Perhaps she just ages *really* well.

Comment: I doubt there's an in-Universe explanation for this. The obvious out of universe explanations would be that the audience is supposed to recognise her, and they already had an actress for a younger Peggy so it doesn't make a lot of sense to hire another one or apply so much make up to the current one that she becomes effectively unrecognisable.

Comment: Hmm.. Let's just go with "ages really well", good choice Cap. :)

Comment: She uses age miracle cream.

Comment: Actually, if you look closely, she does have minor old(er)-age makeup during the 1970 scene. She'd be maybe 55, and during that time period most (?) middle-aged women died their hair, so some facial lines and wrinkling could be all that would indicate aging.

Comment: Yeah, this scene seemed off to me, too. Granted, I guess she has actually aged about 8 years since Captain America. But 8 years is not 30 years.

Comment: Peggy was about 24 during First Avenger (She was born in 1921), so in the scene in 1970 she would be around 50.  There is also a scene int Ant-Man, where she is presented at 68 years old, in 1989.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't get much of a good look of her, as we only see her briefly through a window with blinds. Nonetheless, she does seem to have some streaks of grey hair and is a little wrinkley-er.

Also, she was born in 1921 ([source](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Peggy_Carter)). So in 1970, she would've been either 48 or 49. It's not implausible to me that the woman below is 48 or 49.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct dialogue in the film which addresses this, however there are several possibilities:

1. This could have been an oversight in the film
2. She did look different, it was just difficult to discern
3. The character's use of make-up made it more difficult to discern her character's age
4. The directors simply didn't have a good/viable/economical way to address that specific detail